# Magento 2.3 to 2.3.6 - help - urgent

Tags: upgrade, helper, magento2.3.6

I just updated my Magento instalation from 2.3.3 to 2.3.6.

PHP version 7.3

Everything seamed to fine except when I do reindex. I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Model\GetProductTypesBySkusInterface in /chroot/home/a96f0e0b/stores.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/a96f0e0b/stores.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Invento...', Array)
#1 /chroot/home/a96f0e0b/stores.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Invento...')
#2 /chroot/home/a96f0e0b/stores.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Invento...')
#3 /chroot/home/a96f0e0b/stores.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled-> in /chroot/home/a96f0e0b/stores.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

Do anyone know what this means? And can anyone help me please.

Comment: can you run all commands?

Comment: Yeah except reindex. But our products do not show anymore. It fails on catalogue search.

Comment: rm -rf generated

Comment: @Reshad Zazai what does that command do? And will that fox our reindex issue?

Comment: Your are configure Elasticsearch ?

Comment: We have a cloud solution and we do have an elasticsearch container. With the correct version. The support said it should not be anything with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-> if error in indexing after upgrade then run below sql query in phpmyadmin

```
CREATE
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
VIEW `inventory_stock_1`
AS
SELECT
DISTINCT
legacy_stock_status.product_id,
legacy_stock_status.website_id,
legacy_stock_status.stock_id,
legacy_stock_status.qty quantity,
legacy_stock_status.stock_status is_salable,
product.sku
FROM `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` product
ON legacy_stock_status.product_id = product.entity_id;
```

and run below commands

- Clear `var/generation`
- Clear `var/cache`
- Enable Magento modules: `bin/magento module:enable --all`
- Compile DI `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

hope this helps you:)

Comment: Tried t his and the same error.. Do I need to do upgrade etc after it?

Comment: no need  to upgrade. its related to something else

Comment: updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for all the help I got from you guys,

@Gohil Rajesh, your script worked but was also an issue with a module that also caused the problem. Disabled that and all indexes are now working.

Thanks, everyone!!

Comment: Happy to hear its works now